# pointer and data structure in c

Tags: c, data-structures

```
typedef struct {
        int a;
        short s[2];
} MSG;

MSG *mp, m = {4, 1, 0};
char *fp, *tp;
mp = (MSG *)malloc(sizeof(MSG));
for (fp = (char *)m.s, tp = (char *)mp->s; tp < (char *)(mp+1);)
        *tp++ = *fp++;
```

I need some help about the explanation of this code. I've read some explanations but I'm still not sure about some of them.

1. `fp = (char *)m.s` its meaning is that convert `m.s` to char type pointer and let the `fp` point to it. But `m.s` is the `short[]` in struct, why it convert to a pointer?
2. `tp = (char *)mp->s`, its meaning is that convert the `mp` to char type pointer and let `mp` point to `s`, and let `tp` point to `mp`.
3. `*tp++ == *fp++`. After the 2 converting, in this line, I am not sure whether it has change and how to assignment due to the different size of char and short.

Comment: The loop is an attempt to reinvent `memcpy(mp->s, m.s, sizeof(mp->s));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, all objects except bit-fields are composed of bytes, and you are allowed to access those bytes fairly readily. This code copies the `s` member of `m` to a new location by copying its bytes.

```
MSG *mp, m = {4, 1, 0};
```

That creates a pointer-to-`MSG` named `mp` (for “message pointer”) and an object named `m` of type `MSG`.

```
mp = (MSG *)malloc(sizeof(MSG));
```

That allocates memory for a new `MSG` and sets `mp` to point to that memory.

```
for (fp = (char *)m.s, tp = (char *)mp->s; tp < (char *)(mp+1);)
    *tp++ = *fp++;
```

In `fp = (char *)m.s`: `m.s` is the `s` member of `m`. Since it is an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. This pointer is then converted from a pointer-to-`short` to a pointer-to-`char`. Then `fp` (for “from pointer”) is set to point to that byte.

In `tp = (char *)mp->s`: `mp->s` is the `s` member of the `MSG` pointed to by `mp`. Since it is an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. This pointer is then converted from a pointer-to-`short` to a pointer-to-`char`. Then `tp` (for “to pointer”) is set to point to that byte.

In `tp < (char *)(mp+1)`: `mp` points to the memory allocated for a `MSG`. `mp+1` points one beyond that. Pointer arithmetic is done in units of the pointed-to type, so `mp+1` is one `MSG` beyond `mp`—it is where the next `MSG` would start if there were one. That means it points just after the end of the `MSG` that `mp` points to. Then `(char *)` converts it to a pointer-to-`char`, and `tp < (char *)(mp+1)` is true as long as `tp` is within that `MSG`. As soon as `tp` reaches the end of the `MSG`, the condition is false, and the loop exits.

In `*tp++ = *fp++;`, one byte is copied from where `fp` points (`*fp`) to where `tp` points (`*tp`), and each pointer is incremented.

(Note that the loop may copy more than `s`: It copies all bytes from where `s` starts until the end of the `MSG`. There may be padding in the structure, such as if `int` is eight bytes and requires eight-byte alignment but `short` is only two bytes, so the `short s[2]` member is only four bytes long, and the structure requires four more bytes to make its size a multiple of eight. To copy only the `s` member, the loop condition could be `tp < (char *) (&mp->s + 1)`, to make it point to the end of `mp->s` instead of the end of `*mp`.)

Comment: Thank you very much! After your explanation, I understand the all means.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right, `short[]` is a pointer, but it's a `short` pointer, so it's converted to `char` pointer in order to copy both short values byte to byte. You can use `int` instead of `short` or any other type, `char` pointer will guarantee you copy for all bytes no matter which type you select.
2. Basically `fp` and `tp` are corresponding pointers to source (`m.s`) and destination (`mp->s`) of memory segment containing two `short` values
3. This is an assignment to copy source byte into destination byte. In this case you do not need to know the types of actual values (`short[2]` in this case) and size of the total memory segment.